# Monitor file in Java on Linux 64bits

Tags: java, linux

I'd like to be notified when a file has been created, deleted or changed, but not using polling mechanism.

I have surveyed related Java API that can use.(EX:JNotify, JPathWatch and JXFileWatcher)

Those APIs provide file monitor by using native component on OS. But I met the same problem is that they can't run on Linux 64bits, because native component in those APIs donen't support Linux 64bits, and this confused me for a long time.

I also know that there'll be a WatchService API as part of NIO2 in JDK7, but JDK7 has not released yet.

So, can any one suggest me a better solution? Very Thanks.

Comment: Why not write a poller in Java?  Polling is not always bad and certainly may be preferrable to compiling your own native code.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried [inotify-java](http://wiki.den-4.com/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/inotify-java) ?

Also, as far as I can see, native component of JNotify comes in C-sources, so you can compile it yourself for any platform.

Comment: Very thanks!! I will try it, but I am not familiar with C complier.
I need to study it, hoping not too complicated.

Comment: @Tim, it looks like inotify has "x86_64" binaries, so you won't even need to compile.

Comment: Great! I think inotify-java can run on Linux 64bits. try it latter!

Comment: It works!

'INotify-Java' can run on Linux 64bits, because it provided native components for Linux 32bits and 64bits.

This is a good way to do file monitor on Linux 64bits by adopting inotify-java API directly without any other efforts, but not for other platforms such as Windows or MAC OS.

If you are not running on Linux 64bits, other APIs I mentioned before(JNotify, JPathWatch and JXFileWatcher) are very useful too and can run on different platforms.